# Is there a YSOD in ServiceStack for Unhandled Exceptions?

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-razor

Is there a built-in renderer for unhandled exceptions when using the RazorFormat plugin?

Our service is throwing an exception, but ServiceStack is rendering the corresponding Razor view anyway (just with empty data).  I would have expected Razor to pick up the error in the ResponseStatus property and display something like ASP.Net's YSOD.

Edit: Our DebugMode on HostConfig is set to 'true'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this previous answer on [getting Error Info from a Razor Page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33081140/85785), e.g. You can short-cut your page to just display the Error message with:

```
@if (RenderErrorIfAny()) { return; }
```

You can also specify a [custom fallback Razor Page for different Errors](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Error-Handling#fallback-error-pages).